# Removing Remote Desktop Connections from Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm on a Windows 10 Home machine, x64, attempting to get rid of defunct connections from Remote Desktop Connection. I found two .RDP files and deleted them, and am now looking for a way to delete the drop-down options to use them that I think would still appear in the program.

Unfortunately I can't find the program, nor the registry keys I've seen referenced on helpful web pages where they might be stored.

If I click on the start button or click the windows key and scroll through the available programs, the "R" section of the menu only has "Realtek" in it -- no Remote Desktop Connection available there.

I looked at the list of default program associations and found Remote Desktop Connection for .RDP, but it no longer tells you where the associated program is, just its name.

I went to the command line and used `cd \` and `dir/s/b *remote*.exe"` (and .com and .bat) to look for the program; There were 7 exe entries, none of which looked like they could be it.

I found instructions for modifying the registry to remove "rdb web feeds"; I don't know if those are the same things, but the instructions say to go to registry keys under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\workspaces\`, and I don't have a `workspaces` in that location in the registry.

The user on this computer is not a computer person; I'd rather 'clean up' the drop down instead of leaving it for them to find and having it fail.

If I can't do that, I'd happily remove the whole program, but can't figure out how to do that either. In "Settings / Apps / Apps & features", nothing that looks like it could be the program appears in the apps list. If I enter "Remote" in the search box, nothing shows up.

Comment: Windows Home doesn't have Remote Desktop. What precisely are you trying to find?

Comment: My wife used it for work; it was downloaded and installed on this Windows 10 Home machine.

Comment: In which case I presume you mean this one - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/windowsdesktop

Comment: If you say so -- it says that, once installed, it will be available through the list of programs from the windows key, and there is no such program listed there. Also, it talks about workspaces, and the location given for 'workspaces' in the registry didn't list any. So I'm not sure.

Comment: @rcook - We are actually asking if that’s what you mean.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not sure how to tell -- the webpage says it is for something called Remote Desktop Client that is downloaded instead of being included; the name and the download part fit. There are no screenshots on the webpage, so I can't tell for sure what that looks like. The best I can say is "I think that's it".

Comment: http://woshub.com/how-to-clear-rdp-connections-history/

Comment: @WasifHasan Thanks - THAT's the set of instructions I needed. I wish there were a way to "accept" comments.

Comment: Thank you very much that I could help you with the link!